# Unable to import spring-boot gradle project in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-boot

**Gradle setup for Spring-boot application : build.gradle file i have used sourcesSet where my all java source file resides.**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            //Required repos
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenLocal()
        }
        dependencies {
            //Required dependency for spring-boot plugin
            classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

    bootRepackage { 
         mainClass = 'com.test.app.Application'
    }

    war {
        baseName = 'companies'
        version =  '0.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        //Required dependency for JSP
        providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
                srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
                srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
                srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
                srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
            }
        }
    }

    eclipse { 
        classpath {
            defaultOutputDir = file('web/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes')
        }
    }

    webAppDirName = 'web/WebContent'
    libsDirName = 'war'

    war {
        baseName = baseName
        version = appVersion
        archiveName = warName
    }

    task printClasspath {
        doLast {
            configurations.testRuntime.each { println it }
        }
```

enter image description here[Command Line able to build model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q8NJ.jpg) 
  [When in eclipse while importing gradle project it is showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snsdT.jpg)

Iam unable to import Gradle project in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Gradle plugin for eclipse?

Help -> Eclipse MArketplace -> Search "Gradle" -> Install the Gradle STS integration.

In addition I recomend you change Spring Boot version to '1.3.3.RELEASE'.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
}}
```

Comment: Yes I am having Gradle i am using Eclipse Luna Version: Mars Release (4.5.0),

Comment: Thanks @bor worked for me...may i know what was the problem was ?

Comment: Normally, Eclipse work better with Maven than Gradle so I tought three possible problems: You have not the plugin, the plugin you have was old or you Spring Boot version was enought new.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an update available for the gradle plugin. Once I updated the plugin using eclipse marketplace everything worked fine and project was imported properly.